# Should we merge the "internet-japanese" and "internet-slang" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Are the two tags [internet-japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-japanese) and [internet-slang](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-slang) really the same or is there a case for tagging non-slang Internet Japanese separately, if such a thing exists?

Answer (score 5):

there could be the opinion that not all internet specific language is slang.  That being said, i think they should be merged into [internet-japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-japanese)  and possibly just changed to [internet](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) but that follows up on a different question about leaving "Japanese" within tags.

Comment: I'm for the merging but not the renaming to "internet" since other things, especially websites would get lumped into the same tag.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are referring to with wesbites, do you mind clarifying?

Comment: These sorts of questions: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website